# Not Able to Run Shell Script in Cygwin using java

Tags: java, cygwin

I am trying to run Shell script using java Application. I am using Process builder for the same.

```
  {
            String cmd;
            cmd = "D:/cygwin/bin/bash -c '/bin/app.sh 121 121 1212 12121'";
            System.out.println("EXECING: " + cmd);
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

            in = p.getInputStream();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            System.out.println("OUT:");
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            in = p.getErrorStream();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            System.out.println("ERR:");
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
```

This Code Works Fine when I Uses Simple shell script like.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Call this script with at least 3 parameters, for example
# sh scriptname 1 2 3 4
echo "first parameter is $1"
echo "Second parameter is $2"
echo "Third parameter is $3"
echo "Third parameter is $4"
exit 0
```

Can Any one Suggest me the way where i can Open Cygwin and then parameters to shell script 
becoz. My another Shell script doesn't work at the same location showing error msg.

```
app.sh: line 57: lib/renameapp.sh: No such file or directory
app.sh: line 226: clear: command not found
app.sh: line 69: grep: command not found
app.sh: line 69: cut: command not found
app.sh: line 74: grep: command not found
```

Can Any one Suggest me How to Open Cygwin Terminal using java and Run shell Script using java..

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

You should either setup your `%PATH` environment variable appropriately, or use absolute paths in your shell script.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention I have already Setup my PATH Variable Cygwin\bin

Answer (score 0):

The `PATH` variable is not being set as you expect -- it may be that the environment is being lost when you start the process from Java, or maybe Cygwin is not doing its normal PATH magic because it isn't a login shell, I'm not sure. Either way, just add `export PATH="$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"` to the top of your script and it will almost certainly work again.